# Smart store destroy cache on logout

Tags: force.com, mobile, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

I am new to SalesforceMobileSDK 2.0, I have developed a hybrid application via sencha touch 2.1 using smart store. The problem is that when I logout from salesforce, all data stored in soups destroys.

Is this default behaviour?

I need to save soup data for different-different users, then how can I achieve that with mobile sdk 2.0

Comment: I wouldn't expect that as default, no.  What is your cache config?

Comment: "What is your cache config"? I didn't get it. Does hybrid app have any cache config file?

If yes where?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is by design, refer this bug for this issue on Github Force.com iOS SDK which was closed with the appropriate explanation - [Github Issue 392](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/issues/392)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to post some code, since you're using Sencha Touch we're going to need to know what libraries you are using to control the SmartStore functionality.  In the SDK2.0 which uses the ForceTK library, you need to tell what your cache flow is ... here's an example using a thin wrapper to Force called SmartObjectJS:

https://github.com/joshbirk/ScorecardMobile/blob/master/Scorecard/www/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes its an default behavior. But you can use your own approach to store data locally. iOS has delegate method for application terminate event in that method you can perform database commit:

`- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application`

and for Android you can perform saving before calling `finish()`

Salesforce Mobile SDK for iOS and Android has SmartStore abstraction to SQLite, which uses [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) on iOS and [SQLCipher](http://sqlcipher.net/) on Android. These facilities allows you to store data in JSON format locally on your device. And data can be retrieved by indexes.